# Is it possible to add a new function to the class based view of django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In class-based views of django rest framework, we have by default functions like get, post etc.. Other than that, Is it possible to add our own function? If it is possible how we will refer that in url.

**My required functions**

```
def get_user_by_name(request, name, format=None):
    jobseekers = JobSeeker.objects.filter(name=name)
    serializer = JobseekerSerializer(jobseekers, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def get_user_by_email(request, email, format=None):
    jobseekers = JobSeeker.objects.filter(email=email)
    serializer = JobseekerSerializer(jobseekers, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def get_user_by_school(request, school, format=None):
    schools = SchoolDetails.objects.filter(school=school)
    jobseekers = JobSeeker.objects.filter(email=email)
    serializer = JobseekerSerializer(jobseekers, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def get_user_by_email(request, email, format=None):
    jobseekers = JobSeeker.objects.filter(email=email)
    serializer = JobseekerSerializer(jobseekers, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: You can always override any function with inheritance

Comment: What kind of function are you talking about?  You have get, put, post, patch, etc.  It handles all the standard types.

Comment: @TimmSimpkins. Suppose if I want to add a function like get_search_by_name, which search records with the given name and send the result?

Comment: I think you need to update your question with more information.  Explain why you need a custom http method, because I don't see why you can't just use another method, like POST or PUT and based on a variable passed, run a different function.

Comment: I understand what you are asking to do.  I don't understand why you can't do  using it with the standard http methods.

Comment: @TimmSimpkins. Can you please give me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a `type` variable in your view, and use the available HTTP methods.  Since it appears you are retreiving data, the GET method is usually used for that, but you can truthfully use whatever method you want.  The GET method allows you to put your variables in the URL too, if that's what you want.

Once you put the type variable in the request, you can just use `if` statements to determine what to do with it.

You could also create a different view for each type of request, although that might be overkill.

This is an example assuming use of the GET method:

```
class foo(APIView):
    # This uses the GET method.  POST, PUT, PATCH etc. would use
    # def post(...), def put(...)...
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # Check what type of request is being made and return the proper response.
        if request.POST['type'] == 'get_user_by_name':
            jobseekers = JobSeeker.objects.filter(name=request.POST['name'])
            serializer = JobseekerSerializer(jobseekers, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        elif request.POST['type'] == 'get_user_by_email':
            jobseekers = JobSeeker.objects.filter(email=email)
            serializer = JobseekerSerializer(jobseekers, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        elif ...
```

Comment: I didn't vet this code for doing anything.  I simply copied and pasted yours.